# VBA Debug Mode Skipping

Tags: vba

I have the following code:

```
Public Sub Test1
 Dim RC as myDll.Controller
 Set RC = New myDll.Controller

 RC.DoTask

 Debug.print "1"
 Debug.print "2"
 RC.DoOtherTask

 Msgbox "Help Me!"
End Sub
```

When I use debug mode and step through the code, hitting the F8 key, as soon as I hit F8 after RC.DoTask, all the code up to the msgbox executes.  My immediate window has the printed lines, rc.DoOtherTask has ran.

Has anyone ever seen this?

It is completely repeatable, but only within the version of VBA that shipped with the product I'm using.

Comment: Have you tried to invert the orders for `RC.DoTask` and `RC.DoOtherTask`? This way you'll know for sure the problem is specifically in `RC.DoTask`...

Comment: Yes I have, it's always caused by RC.DoTask.

I've also implemnted RC.DoTask in VBA, and when I run through it with Shift + F8, I get the exact same behavior.

Comment: You mentioned "version of VBA" and "product". May I ask what that is?

Comment: Also, what's `RC.DoTask` supposed to do? Maybe it's sending some key commands to windows...

Comment: I am just wild guessing maybe the doTask changed the behaviour on F8 ? something like Application.onKey "{F8}" ...
So, can you "Step Into" next line using the icon in VBA Editor? Please try , thanks

Comment: The product is a terminal emulator.  RC.DoTask hits the enter key in the emulator and waits for the emulator screen to be updated.

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint in the Debug.Print line? Does it stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The software vendor came back and said it was a coding issue on their end.  This was not related to VBA, the VBA editor, etc.